# Wrapping html elements given a condition in phoenix templating

Tags: html, syntax, elixir, phoenix-framework

I would like to wrap and element in an `a` tag, but only given a certain condition.

The code looks like this, but I'm sure there must be a better way.

```
<%= if condition do %>
<a href="/">
<% end %>

<p>Text</p>

<%= if condition do %>
</a>
<% end %>
```

What would be a nicer way to write this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of any way to make this more elegant than what you've already written if you only want to use this once, but if you want a reusable function that does conditional wrapping of some content in an HTML tag with arbitrary attributes, I'd use a helper function like this:

View:

```
defmodule MyApp.PageView do
  use MyApp.Web, :view

  def content_tag_if(condition, name, attrs, [do: content]) do
    if condition do
      content_tag name, attrs, [do: content]
    else
      content
    end
  end
end
```

Template:

```
<%= content_tag_if 1 > 2, :a, [href: "/"] do %>
  <p>Text</p>
<% end %>

<%= content_tag_if 1 < 2, :a, [href: "/"] do %>
  <p>Text</p>
<% end %>
```

Output:

```
<p>Text</p>
<a href="/">
  <p>Text</p>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would certainly use a function declared in the proper View's module:

```
def wrap_in_a_if_condition(html_text, href, condition) do
  if condition do
    # here build A - propably using [Phoenix.HTML.link/2][1]
  else
    html_text
  end
end
```

And then you can use it for all templates for that view. If you need to have it globally, you can import in other views.